# could not connect to ejabberd server: unknown host exception

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

unknown host exception coming while connecting to ejabberd server.

```
public static final String HOST = "http://54.254.220.129:5280/admin";
public static final int PORT = 5222;
public static final String SERVICE = "localhost";
public static final String USERNAME = "admin@localhost";
public static final String PASSWORD = "########";



ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
enter code here
            try {
                connection.connect();
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                        "[SettingsDialog] Connected to "
                                + connection.getHost());
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                        "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "
                                + connection.getHost());
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                setConnection(null);
            }
```

any answer will be appreciable !
thanks

Comment: i dont know why this question is down voted.
i tried many solutions in stack overflow.but i cant identify what is my problem.But after some good answer from my question, i found what mistake i made in my code .
Thanks for the team stack overflow and one suggestion if any body down vote a question please let them to make their comment , this will be more help full  a beginner like me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Traditional XMPP doesn't use HTTP

You can't connect to `http://54.254.220.129:5280/admin` (this is for browsers!)

You need to use just the IP address

```
public static final String HOST = "54.254.220.129";
```

Comment: hi martin thanks for you support.
i have no idea about XMPP server. could you please tell me how can i use eJabberd server for my chat application.i already have a xmpp client. and above ip itself contain a web page. i installed XMPP server to 54.254.220.129:5280/admin . if i use the i p what is mt SERVICE_NAME in XMPPConnection

Comment: port 5280 servers the HTML webpage, and doesn't have anything to do with XMPP. Connect to 5222 with your XMPP client. I would recommend you use just use `new ConnectionConfiguration("54.254.220.129", 5222);` so you can avoid service name for now.

Comment: but now its showing XMPPError connecting to 54.254.220.129:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to 54.254.220.129:5222.
  -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /54.254.220.129 (port 5222): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Answer (score 3):

In your HOST string you already wrote the port number. So i think you need to write only ip address without port and admin like `http://54.254.220.129`.
- After that try to connect. And try to login.

Try this;

```
public static final String HOST = "http://54.254.220.129";
public static final int PORT = 5222;
public static final String SERVICE = "localhost";
public static final String USERNAME = "admin@localhost";
public static final String PASSWORD = "########";

ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

connection.connect();
connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

Comment: thanks for you kind support now i'm able to connect with  host

Comment: and one more thing 5222 is reserved for C2S connection . so ned only ip as host with out http://